# NMaximize error: The function is value....is not a number

Tags: mathematical-optimization, warning-messages

I cannot manage to solve this problem:

$$max_{p1,p2} \hspace{0.1cm} (p1 - w1) * \frac{\exp(beta*x1 - alpha*p1)}{1 + \exp(beta*x1 - alpha*p1) + exp(beta*x2 - alpha*p2)}$$
$$ + (p2 - w2) * \frac{exp(beta*x2 - alpha*p2)}{1 + \exp(beta*x1 - alpha*p1) + \exp(beta*x2 - alpha*p2)}$$

I tried two things:

```
NMaximize[{(p1-w1)*(Exp[beta * x1-alpha * p1]/(1 + Exp[beta * x1 - alpha* p1] + Exp[beta * x2 - alpha * p2])) + (p2-w2)*(Exp[beta * x2-alpha * p2]/(1 + Exp[beta * x1 - alpha * p1] + Exp[beta * x2 - alpha * p2])), p1 >= 0 , p2 >= 0},{p1,p2}]
```

and then secondly

```
fun[p1_?NumericQ, p2_?NumericQ] := (p1-w1)*(Exp[beta * x1-alpha * p1]/(1 + Exp[beta * x1 - alpha * p1] + Exp[beta * x2 - alpha * p2])) + (p2-w2)*(Exp[beta * x2-alpha * p2]/(1 + Exp[beta * x1 - alpha* p1] + Exp[beta * x2 - alpha * p2]))
```

and

```
NMaximize[{fun[p1,p2],p1>=0,p2>=0},{p1,p2}]
```

Both times, I get this error (`NMaximize::nnum`):
[image]

Anybody have an idea why I am getting this error?

Edit1:

Since starting, I have also now just derived the FOC manually and use this code:

```
Solve[{
  (Exp[betax1 - alphap1]/(1 + Exp[betax1 - alphap1] + 
        Exp[betax2 - alphap2])) + (p1 - 
       w1)*(-alpha*(Exp[
          betax1 - alphap1]/(1 + Exp[betax1 - alphap1] + 
           Exp[betax2 - alphap2])) (1 - (1/(1 + 
             Exp[betax1 - alphap1] + 
             Exp[betax2 - alphap2])))) + (alpha (Exp[
           betax2 - alphap2]/(1 + Exp[betax1 - alphap1] + 
            Exp[betax2 - alphap2]))/(1 + Exp[betax1 - alphap1] + 
          Exp[betax2 - alphap2])) (p2 - w2) == 0,
  (Exp[betax2 - alphap2]/(1 + Exp[betax1 - alphap1] + 
        Exp[betax2 - alphap2])) + (p2 - 
       w2)*(-alpha (Exp[
          betax2 - alphap2]/(1 + Exp[betax1 - alphap1] + 
           Exp[betax2 - alphap2])) (1 - (1/(1 + 
             Exp[betax1 - alphap1] + 
             Exp[betax2 - alphap2])))) + (alpha (Exp[
           betax1 - alphap1]/(1 + Exp[betax1 - alphap1] + 
            Exp[betax2 - alphap2]))/(1 + Exp[betax1 - alphap1] + 
          Exp[betax2 - alphap2]))*(p1 - w1) == 0},
 {p1, p2}]
```

Do you think I would need to use `Reduce` here? I ran this code and it would not solve after 24 hours, any ideas what's wrong?

Comment: Welcome to the Mathematica Stack Exchange. Please include Mathematica code (not images)  that can be copied, pasted and executed. Thanks.

Comment: I added it, is this correct like this?

Comment: Your  approaches don't work because parameters `alfa, betam ...` aren't defined

Comment: Ok, if I just want them to be a real and positive number. How would I go about that?

Comment: In that case you should use `Maximize`, because `NMaximize` needs numerical input.

Comment: Ok. When I try that, it does not do anything. Am I doing something wrong?

It just repeats the code that I give to it as the OUT:
Maximize[{(p1-w1)*(Exp[beta * x1-alpha * p1]/(1 + Exp[beta * x1 - alpha* p1] + Exp[beta * x2 - alpha * p2])) + (p2-w2)*(Exp[beta * x2-alpha * p2]/(1 + Exp[beta * x1 - alpha * p1] + Exp[beta * x2 - alpha * p2])), p1 >= 0 , p2 >= 0},{p1,p2}]

Comment: Also, I tried now to put Simplify[Maximize[{...}],{alpha>0, beta >0, w1>0, w2>0, x1>0, x2>0}]

Unfortunately, this also didnt work. The program just changed the stuff inside the Maximize function but didnt solve it.

Comment: @Jakob Look at `p1d=Numerator[Simplify[D[yourexpr,p1]]];p2d=Numerator[Simplify[D[yourexpr,p2]]];Reduce[{p1d==0,p2d==0},{p1,p2}]` Can you help `Reduce` by eliminating non-zero multipliers? Or tell it variable domains? Any way to get that simple enough to get solutions? Then you can try to decide which solutions are maximums. This probably won't work or MMA would have done that itself. But maybe it will give you something that you can recognize and use.

Comment: Hi Bill, my answer didnt fit here, so I put it in an answer box below